# How to handle embedded flash active x control script errors?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flash

I have a winForm panel that has a flash ative x control embedded in it.  This works pretty well.

I load the form, add the flash control to the form, then load the .swf file that I wish to play.  However, I have a few issues.  There is a button in the swf file that is loaded that is marked with an 'x' to denot that it should close the flash plugin.

When this button is clicked it pops an internet explorer window and then shows an error dialog box that says: "Internet Explorer cannot download . Unspecified error"

There is also a 'Continue' button in the flash movie that shows when the movie is over, and it produces the same behavior when the button is clicked.

For this project we are trying to aviod the usage of the WebBrowser control to host the flash video.

Does anyone have any solutions that would allow the application to handle a call that opens a new internet explorer window?

EDIT: I have found more details as to what specifically the issue is.  The flash file (.swf) has an embedded call to IE:

```
javascript:window.close()
```

This particular call is causing the IE window to pop and then fail.  We do not have the ability to change the flash file, is there anyway to handle this call from the windows form and stop it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you steal this SWF?

But to answer you change your embed code.

```
attributes.allowscriptaccess = "never"
```

Comment: No the swf is provided by someone for me to display in a .net app.  Thanks for the answer, I will test it out and vote up if it works.